# How to Limit the Div Exactly into the Screen Size

Tags: html, css

this is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tela Cheia no CSS</title>
<link href="Styles 02B.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="cabecalho"></div>
<div id="conteudo">
<p>Texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
<p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
</div>
<div id="rodape"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css code:

```
body {
    margin: 90px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF501;
    border: thick solid #FF0B0F;
}

#cabecalho {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2A00FF;
    border: thick solid #49FF00;
    height: 90px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#conteudo {
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F108D3;
    border: thick solid #FFBE00;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#rodape {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2A00FF;
    border: thick solid #49FF00;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I want exactly this but with a small difference: the hole header (and footer and content) inside the screen size, including the border. note that the border on the right is out of the screen and I need this inside the screen. just that.

if any of you know how to get that, please, help me. I'd appreciate your help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `*{box-sizing: border-box}`

```css
        *{box-sizing: border-box}
        body {
            margin: 90px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #FFF501;
            border: thick solid #FF0B0F;
        }

        #cabecalho {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #2A00FF;
            border: thick solid #49FF00;
            height: 90px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #conteudo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 90px; /*add this it is the height of #cabecalho*/
            left: 0;
            bottom: 50px; /*add this it is the height of #rodape*/
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #F108D3;
            border: thick solid #FFBE00;
            z-index: 2;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }

        #rodape {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #2A00FF;
            border: thick solid #49FF00;
            height: 45px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

```html
     <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tela Cheia no CSS</title>
        <link href="Styles 02B.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="cabecalho"></div>
        <div id="conteudo">
        <p>Texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        <p>Texto de exemplo...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rodape"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: noooooooo... you are kidding! just that? thanks a lot, Tambo.

Comment: but, Tambo. the footer is hiding the scroll on the bottom. I need to put the content filling up the area in between the header and footer automatically. could you help me? thanks.

Comment: all the minutes to Mrs. Tambo!

Comment: check the update just replace the height with `height: calc(100vh - 145px);`

Comment: it didn't work, Tambo. i changed the height of the content to the one you told, unsuccessfully.

Comment: check the demo or add height: `-webkit-calc(100vh - 145px);-moz-height: calc(100vh - 145px);height: calc(100vh - 145px);`

Comment: where's the demo link?

Comment: Tambo. I just removed the calc from the content height but I still gives me the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67241/discussion-between-tambo-and-thor-my).

Comment: now I see the change in fiddle.
Tambo. why should I fix the top and bottom of the content div? why doen't it go automatically?

Comment: Because it is the beginning and the end of the content and you are using position fixed, if you want it to go automatically you can use percentage.

Comment: is there any chance of I fix the header on top and fix the footer on bottom (just as it is now) and fill the space in between the header and bottom automatically? if yes, how?

Comment: If they don't have a fixed height then you can use javascript for that, but in your case they have a fixed height so the solution above is what you need or you can use `calc` too but that is css3

Comment: thanks, Tambo. I think this is the best solution for my application. thanks for your assistance. a big hug from Brasil.

Answer (score 0):

I still get confused of your question.
Is this what you mean?

Use iframe to handle it.

I use my blog to try this:

```
<iframe align="top" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="600" width="600" src="http://www.appacyber.net/test.php"></iframe>
```

**[check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/yv7186zn/)**